# jQuery or JavaScript autocomplete element creation

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Using something like jQuery autocomplete, I want to dynamically create elements just like the tags are displayed a Wordpress during a Post/Page creation. So I will need an input text element that triggers on the enter key or pressing a button.

My question is there already a javascript / jQuery library or plugin that's already available?

Or is this easily extractable from the wordpress source? I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

I'd even tag the javascript thats being used on stackoverflow on their tags input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquerytag

It contains an Input field to which you can add autocomplete to in my opinion.

Comment: yes, something like that, that is similar to how stackoverflow does it, I'll take a look at the source to see if its worth starting as a baseline.

Comment: It should be pretty simple to trigger the 'tag close-off'. Just search for 'data-seperator' in the plugin.

Comment: Ah, there is a `addOnEnter : true` as well!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the jQuery UI autocomplete "multiple values" example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple?

Comment: Yes, but that is just string manipulation of the input box, I'd rather  have the box cleared and an element created with an 'X' to remove rather than the user removing manually with more key presses.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I misunderstood the question.